# MaterialModule not working in some modules: 'mat-card' is not a known element

Tags: angular, import, module, angular-material

I've found similar questions, but none seems to be the problem I'm having.

Currently my app uses a postModule, which is lazy-loaded, while the other modules are loaded normally. They all use Angular Material, which I've added to a materialModule. The use of my materialModule works fine for my postModule components, however it doesn't work with my aboutModule (and possibly other modules aswell).

My apologies for the amount of code. I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm not sure where to start looking for this problem.

**AboutModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AboutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule
  ]
})
export class AboutModule { }
```

**MaterialModule**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import {
  MatListModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule
} from "@angular/material";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatListModule,
    //other Mat imports
  ],
  exports: [
    MatListModule,
    //Rest of the imports
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { httpInterceptorProviders } from './http-interceptors';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MainNavComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [httpInterceptorProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SelectivePreloadStrategy } from './selective-preload-strategy';
import { AuthGuard } from './user/auth.guard';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about/about.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map/map.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news/news.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'post',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './post/post.module#PostModule',
    data: { preload: true }
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'post/list', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'news', component: NewsComponent},
  {path: 'map', component: MapComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
      {preloadingStrategy: SelectivePreloadStrategy}),
  ],

  declarations: [
    AboutComponent,
    NewsComponent,
    MapComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not loading the "aboutModule", you are just importing the component. I suggest you make a routing module for the "aboutModule" which will handle its childs and then load your route module as you did in the post one.